# disable button from another component if form in sibling component is not valid

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms, disabled-input

I have wrapper with 3 component (let say sibling1, sibling2, sibling3)

```
<div class="m-row m-row--forms column1">
      <div class="column2"><sibling1></sibling1></div>
      <div class="column2"><sibling2></sibling2></div>
      <div class="column1"><sibling3></sibling3></div>
</div>
```

In sibling1 and sibling2 i have forms, in sibling3 I have action buttons.

I want to disable button ('save') in sibling3 if sibling1 form and sibling2 form are invalid

like:

```
<button type="button" [disabled] ="!sibling1Form.valid && !sibling2Form.valid">SAVE</button>
```

right now my sibling3 doesn't know what is sibling1Form and sibling2Form so it show error

```
Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
```

how can I tell button if these forms are valid or not?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the `valid` states to the component:

```
<sibling-3 [validStates]="{sibling1: siblingForm1.valid, sibling2: siblingForm2.valid"></sibling-3>
```

And:

```
export class SiblingThree {
  @Input() validStates: any;
}
```

Then you can check like:

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="!validStates?.sibling1?.valid && !validStates?.sibling2?.valid">SAVE</button>
```

**EDIT:**

It's worth mentioning that this solution won't work unless you have the forms in the parent component and pass them in as `@Input`s as well. So something like this:

```
<sibling-1 [form]="siblingFormOne"></sibling-1>
<sibling-2 [form]="siblingFormTwo"></sibling-2>
<sibling-2 [form]="siblingFormThree"></sibling-2>
```

And every sibling component would also have:

```
@Input() form: any; // Can be changed for FormGroup if that's what you're using
```

Then in each sibling component you would bind the form properties to the `form` property instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a service for that.

Inject your service in all of your components, and use a property such as `AreBothFormsValid = true`.

All you have to do now is use a `*ngIf`in your thrid component.